# Clojure: Same vector values in a row checker

Tags: clojure

I'm creating an Clojure Tic Tac Toe game, where I have a board variable with 9 numbers `(def moves [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0])` . This variable gets filled with 1's en 2's (no "x" or "o" yet). At the end of the game the variable could look like `[2 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 2]` where 1 owns the second row. Now I need a function to check if there's three in a row. I wanted to start horizontally. Which means I need a function to check if there's after each 3 numbers 3 of the same number are in a row. any ideas how I can create a function like this? 
So this is the function so far:

```
(def moves [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0])
(defn wongame? [playedmoved]
  (
    (def counter 0)
    ;action here....  
    )
 )
(won moves) ;gives true/false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
(defn end-of-game? [moves]
  (->> moves
       (partition 3)
       (remove #(= [0 0 0] %))
       (map (partial apply =))
       (some identity)))
```

With your example input of [2 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 2] `(partition 3)` gives:

```
((2 1 2) (1 1 1) (2 1 2))
```

We need to use `=` with each list. `apply` is required because `=` works with individual arguments rather than a list. `partial` is required because the parameters to `apply =` are pending. `#(apply = %)` could have equivalently been used.

```
(false true false)
```

`some` is all about '(at least) one or none'. Here if one of the list it is passed is truthy then that one will be returned.

If you really need the answer to return true/false then put a call to `boolean` as the last function to the thread last macro (`->>`). I've left that out because only rarely do you need to actually return true or false in Clojure - you can rely on *nil punning*.

This same function will work for vertically as well. Start off with a general `transpose` function that works for a matrix (e.g. `[[0 0 0][0 0 0][0 0 0]]`):

```
(defn transpose [matrix]
  (apply mapv vector matrix))
```

Then fashion your input before, and its output after:

```
(defn transpose-flat [xs]
  (->> xs
       (partition 3)
       transpose
       (mapcat identity)))
```

Comment: Yep thats something like it, but my moves starts with 9 zero's, which will mean the method returns true at the start.

Comment: So it is three in a row, but they can't be zeros?

Comment: Yeah, see 1 as an "x" an 2 as "o" and zero as a not filled space

Comment: Thanks for the help! It took me some time to get the transpose to work since it expects a partitioned vector. So when i partition the moves, than transpose and than check if end-of-game? without the partition part it works vertically too.

Comment: Sorry my bad. `transpose` assumes a matrix, so `[[0 0 0][0 0 0][0 0 0]]`. Keeping your data structure you would have to `partition-all` before calling and do something like `mapcat identity` after.

Comment: Is there a way to un-partition? That means I transpose the moves and then put them in 1 list again?

Comment: Thats exacly that i needed, it works perfectly thanks again.
Now for the vertical check i do 
`(if (end-of-game? (flatten (transpose (partition 3 moves))))`

Answer (score 2):

```
(def moves [0 0 1 1 0 1 2 2 2]) #_"the game's state in the middle"
```

At first, if we encounter like this pattern, we need stop the game,
Otherwise we are possible to misjudge the winner of this game 
if the moves reaches the state like [2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 2]. Which is the winner? We need to call this function each turn of the game.

Second, the name "won?" isn't appropriate because this function doesn't tell the winner, but tells the end of game. "won?" function should be renamed like ["end-of-game?" "game-end?" "end?"].

Third, I try to implement "winner" that returns the winner of the game like this:

```
(defn winner [moves]
  (let [pattern-of-end {[1 1 1]:1 [2 2 2]:2}]
    (->> moves          #_"I use threading macro to explain"
         (partition 3)  #_"group by each three symbols. 
                           1 line of 9 elements -> 3 lines of 3 elements"
         (keep pattern-of-end) #_"If there is some lines that matches 
                                  the pattern-of-end ,that will return [1] or [2]"
         first          #_"Because the previous expression returns lazy-seq 
                        we can get the scalar by calling first"
)))
```

This tells us the winner of the game.

Comment: `winner` might also be a good name. I would not use a question mark i.e. `winner?`, unless I expected the function would pretty much always be used as a predicate.

Answer (score 2):

It would have been easier if you had proper numbers for x's and o's:

```
(defn the-winner-is [moves]
    (let [x 5
          o 7]
        (->> moves
             (partition 3)
             (map (partial apply +))
             (some #{15 21}))))
```

This way it even says who is the winner (15 or 21).

```
(the-winner-is [5 5 7 7 7 0 7 7 7]) ; 21
(the-winner-is [5 5 5 7 7 5 5 7 7]) ; 15
(the-winner-is [5 7 5 7 7 5 5 7 5]) ; nil
```